# Dataset values used in strings

Tags: database, vb.net, string, dataset

This is driving me nuts, and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. 
I have a dataset and a summary label control is a string made up of a few dataset columns. It looks like this;

```
Dim EngDetailsStr As String
Dim str1 As String =  MDataSet.EnginesPool.Item(i).Item("EngInstalledPosition").ToString '(OR REMOVE THE .TOSTRING, it still dont work)
Dim str2 As String = MDataSet.EnginesPool.Item(i).Item("EngModelDisplayName").ToString
EngDetailsStr = ("Engine Location - " & str1 & "-" & str2)
```

OR (If i tried:)

```
EngDetailsStr = "Engine Serial: -" & MDataSet.EnginesPool.Item(i).Item("EngInstalledPosition")
```

Both ending with;

```
Label1.text = EndDetailsStr
```

What ever i do the strings eng up as: "Engine Location - " without the dataset values appended to the string.

The dataset values are not blank, they are just strings, (thats checked further up in the code). Why on earth isnt this working?

Is there some special Database String that needs to be casted to a normal string?

Thanks Internet,

EDIT: ENTIRE LOOP BLOCK CODE

```
For i As Integer = 0 To MaintraxDataSet.EnginesPool.Rows.Count - 1
    EngLineLabel(i) = New Label
            With EngLineLabel(i)
                .Name = "EngLabel" & i
                .ForeColor = Color.White
                .Visible = True
                Dim pointlabel As Point
                pointlabel.X = 60
                pointlabel.Y = 55 + (i * 25)
                .Location = pointlabel
                .BringToFront()
                Dim EngDetailsStr As String
                If IsDBNull(MaintraxDataSet.EnginesPool.Item(i).Item("EngSerialNumber")) Then
                    EngDetailsStr = ("Engine " & i & " Not found. Data Error.")
                Else
                    Dim str1 As String = MaintraxDataSet.EnginesPool.Item(i).Item("EngInstalledPosition").ToString
                    Dim str2 As String = MaintraxDataSet.EnginesPool.Item(i).Item("EngModelDisplayName").ToString
                    EngDetailsStr = "Engine Location - " & str1 & "-" & str2
                End If
                .Text = EngDetailsStr
            End With
            'Create the label
            Panel1.Controls.Add(EngLineLabel(i))
    Next
```

Comment: `The dataset values are not blank` : I don't believe you.  Can you prove it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is not like other forum sites. Here the focus is creating a vast number of good quality questions with good quality answers. If you ask a question and get the answer you want that's just a side-effect of the overall purpose of this site. Your goal should be to write a good question to help future users of the site. So to that end, your questions should contain good, minimal, and working code that reproduces the problem you're facing. Can you please include code that we can run that demonstrates the issue you have?

Comment: Since we don't know what is `MDataSet.EnginesPool.Item(i).Item` I can only suggest that you put breakpoint on that line and mouse over this, and see what is inside

Comment: If i put 'label1.text = MDataSet.EnginesPool.Item(i).Item("EngInstalledPosition")' the desired text is printed. (the item in the dataset, which is a text string set in a datagrid view on another form) It seems to be the '&' operator is not working for these strings.

Comment: A break point on the line 'engDetailsStr= "Engine Location - " & str1' shows that str1 contains 'No1 Engine' but still the resultant 'label1,text = endDetailsStr' only prints "Engine Location -"

Its weird?

Comment: May be you looking into wrong iteration in your loop

Comment: No, thats alright. Same problem somewhere else to: .Text = "Engine - " & Row("EngSerialNumber") just prints "Engine -" not the full label. Change it to '.text = Row("EngSerialNumber") and the labels text is the serial stored in that row.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when you add to the label control:

```
.AutoSize = true
```

Apparently if you dynamicaly create a label this is set to false as default. Adding the text from the dataset made the string to long for the label control, so the last string would be truncated.

Hence when: '

```
 Dim str1 As String = MaintraxDataSet.EnginesPool.Item(i).Item("EngInstalledPosition").ToString
 Dim str2 As String = MaintraxDataSet.EnginesPool.Item(i).Item("EngModelDisplayName").ToString
 NewLabel1.text = "Engine Location - " & str1 & "-" & str2
```

Would truncate the string and only display "Engine Location - "

however:'

```
  NewLabel1.autosize = true 
  NewLabel1.Text = "Engine Location - " & str1 & "-" & str2
```

Works fine.

Thought Id leave this up here in case anyone else has this issue. Thanks.